# Mongoid find not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, factory-bot

I have Group and User models. User belongs to Group, Group has many Users.

I'm writing an integration test with Rspec: When a Group has at least one User, the Group is not deleted.

**Factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group_with_users do
    name 'Demo group'

    ignore do
      users_count 2
    end

    after(:create) do |group, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, evaluator.users_count, group: group)
    end
  end
end
```

**Spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'admin can manage groups' do
  background do
    @group_spec = FactoryGirl.create(:group_with_users)

    visit groups_path
  end

  scenario "don't delete group because it's not empty (there are users)" do
    page.should have_text(@group_spec.name)

    # DEBUGGING
    binding.pry

    click_link 'Delete'

    page.should have_text('Not deleted')
    page.should have_text(@group_spec.name)
  end
end
```

**Groups Controller:**

```
def destroy
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])

  # DEBUGGING
  binding.pry

  msg = if @group.users.size > 1
          'Not deleted'
        else
          @group.delete
          'Deleted'
        end

  redirect_to groups_path, notice: msg
end
```

The problem is that the **group is being deleted**. So I decide to debug (see #DEBUGGING in spec and controller) the code.

In spec:

```
@group_spec.users.size
>> 2
```

**But** in controller:

```
@group.users.size
>> 0
```

Comparing two objects:

```
@group === @group_spec
>> true
```

**EDIT:**
In spec debugging:

```
Group.find(@group_spec._id).users.size
>> 0
```

PS: The "datamodel" is a little bit more complex. But that's the idea.

Comment: Oh! Why? ... I'm using Mongoid::Paranoia module, so I'm soft removing the document.

Comment: `delete` doesn't trigger callbacks. btw, I guess: `@group_spec.valid? => false`

Comment: heck, at least I contributed a bit :)

Comment: what about `@group_spec.users.map(&:valid?)`

Comment: `@group_spec.users.map(&:valid?) => [true]` ... users_count = 1

Comment: damn and `@group_spec.users.map(&:persisted?)` ?

Comment: `@group_spec.users.map(&:persisted?) >> [true]`

Comment: :) well can't see how i could help you.. sorry

Comment: Can you show us the relations you've defined on the User and Group models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your factory and didn't actually put any users in your group. It should look like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group_with_users do
    name 'Demo group'

    ignore do
      users_count 2
    end

    after(:create) do |group|
      group.users << FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, users_count, group: group)
    end
  end
end
```

Your debugging session was also misleading because `@group` and `@group_spec` are actually different instances, which is why they have different data. You can verify this by checking the `object_id` or calling `equal?`.  `===` is equality used for case statements. (See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) for an explanation of the different comparison operators.) ActiveRecord considers two records the same (in the `==` and `===` sense) if they have the same `id`.

Comment: Thanks @davogones, but I got the same... I didn't add it in the question but I have to make sure that users belongs to same group's account:     `after(:create) { |group, evaluator| FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, evaluator.users_count, group: group, account: group.account) }` ...

Comment: I assumed your group model should have taken care of the inverse relationship automatically - that's how I would have done it. Nevertheless, I fixed the code to match the way you'd like to have it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you tell me, why `@group === @group_spec
>> true`, but `@group_spec.users.size >> 2 and @group.users.size >> 0` with previous factory?

Comment: `@group` and `@group_spec` are different instances. I added the explanation to my answer.